# call Load more function for active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a load more function for a specific tab pane, in this case, the active tab pane. I'm having issues with this jquery function because I'm calling the load more in the end of all tabs, and in my JS function I can't figure out how to load after the pane that is active, in which the button was clicked. This way I keep loading the questions in the last pane, but I couldnt print without `var lastItem = $('div.question-col .question-summary:last');`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".load-more").on('click', function (e) {
        var tab = $(this).data('tab');
        var next_page = $(this).data('next-page');
        console.log(next_page);
        console.log(tab);
        $.get($(this).data('url') + '?tab=' + tab + '&page=' + next_page, function (data) {
            addNewQuestions($.parseJSON(data));
        });
        $(this).data('next-page', parseInt(next_page) + 1);
    });

    siteStats();
});

function addNewQuestions(objects) {

    $.each(objects, function (i, object) {
        console.log(object);
        var lastItem = $('div.question-col .question-summary:last');
        var newLine = lastItem.clone(true);

        var newObject = newLine.find('.question-info');

        updateTitleAndLink(newObject.find('.summary a'), object);
        updateCreationDate(newObject.find('.question-updated-at'), object);
        updateQuestionAnswers(newObject.find('.question-answers'), object);
        updateAnswerCount(newObject.find('.answers-count'), object);
        updateViewsCount(newObject.find('.views-count'), object);
        updateVotesCount(newObject.find('.votes-count'), object);
        updateSolvedStatus(newObject.find('.status'), object)

        lastItem.after(newLine);
    });
}
```

The update functions are not relevant to this case, I guess.

```
<div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#recent_questions">Recent Questions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#unanswered_questions">Unanswered Questions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#top">Top Scored Questions</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    {if empty($recent_questions)}
                        <div class = "col-sm-12" style = "text-align: center"><strong>No questions to load!</strong></div>
                    {/if}
                    {if !empty($recent_questions)}
                        <div id="recent_questions" class="question-col">
                            <!-- Questions come here -->

                            <div class = "load-more"
                                 data-next-page = "1"
                                 data-url = "{url('controller/api/questions/load_more_questions')}"
                                 data-tab = "recent_questions">
                                <a id="loadMore">
                                    Load More...
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {/if}

                    <div id="unanswered_questions">
                        <!-- Questions come here -->

                        <div class = "load-more"
                             data-next-page = "1"
                             data-url = "{url('controller/api/questions/load_more_questions')}"
                             data-tab = "unanswered_questions">
                            <a id="loadMore">
                                Load More...
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="top">
                        <!-- Questions come here -->

                        <div class = "load-more"
                             data-next-page = "1"
                             data-url = "{url('controller/api/questions/load_more_questions')}"
                             data-tab = "top_scored_questions">
                            <a id="loadMore">
                                Load More...
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

`//Questions come here` - Question template

```
<div class="question-summary narrow">

    <div class="question-info col-md-12">

        <div class="votes">
            <div class="votes-count">
                <span title="{$question['votes_count']} votes">
                    {if $question['votes_count']}
                        {$question['votes_count']}
                    {else}
                        0
                    {/if}
                    </span>
            </div>
            <div>votes</div>
        </div>

        <div {if $question['solved_date']}
            class="status answered-accepted"
        {else}
            class="status answer-selected"
        {/if}
                title="one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer">
            <div class="answers-count">
                <span title="{$question['answers_count']} answer">{$question['answers_count']}</span></div>
            <div>answer</div>
        </div>
        <div class="views">
            <div class="views-count">
                <span title="{$question['views_counter']} views">{$question['views_counter']}</span></div>
            <div>views</div>
        </div>

        <div class="summary question-title">
            <h3>
                <a href="{questionUrl($question['publicationid'])}"
                   data-base-question-url = "{questionUrl('')}"
                   style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.4; margin-bottom: .5em;">
                    {$question['title']}
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>


        <div class = "statistics col-sm-12 text-right" style="padding-top: 8px">
            <span>
                <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
                <span class="question-updated-at">{$question['creation_date']}</span>
            </span>
            <span>
                <i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
                <span class="question-answers">{$question['answers_count']}</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My question is: is there any way to put my loaded content after the last item of the active pane?

Kind regards

Comment: The data-tab for your last div is 'top_scored_questions' but div id is 'top'.

Comment: Also, you can keep reference to active_tab outside your functions and update it every time .load_more is clicked. Then pass the active_tab to addNewQuestions so that you would attach the loaded data to active tab.

Comment: How can I attach the loaded data to active tab? @vabii

Comment: I tried something like this `var lastItem = $(".question-col#tab.question-summary:last");`. Not working though

Comment: added suggestions/corrections as an answer of what I meant keeping reference to current tab.

Comment: I understand what you said, but everything is working, the place where I load the content is the problem. I just want a way to select my last `question-summary` from que `question-col` with id `tab`.

Comment: There is no element with quesiton-summary class in you html. Please show how your html would be. I thought the content is not loading in correct tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144428/discussion-between-luis-costa-and-vabii).

Comment: I added the `question-summary` template. It comes after the `question-col`.
They are all printing , the only problem is that they are being printed in the end of the last tab, last question

Comment: the css selector for last child is :last-child, so try var lastItem = $('div.question-col .question-summary:last-child');